# How can Apple approve app with BankID login

Tags: appstore-approval, bankid

Apple requires a demo login in order to approve an app for the Store. I am wondering how to provide Apple with a login where BankID is involved

BankID is an App which the user normally has on her device (can be on PC to). It contains a signed encrypted identity provided by the user's Bank.

A login involves a bunch of API calls between our app, our backend and the BankID server

Now users dont have to remember a username/password for each service. The username is your SSN number and password is a secret code that you enter into the BankID app when logging into a service

I can use a special Test BankID app for dev and test. But our app, submitted to the app store will be production. This essentially makes it impossible for Apple to login and approve. Is there anyone who has succeded down this path?

Alternatively, one could provide a backdoor in our server which short-circuits the BankID security for a specific login ID provided to Apple. This can be disabled most of the time.

thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

What I've seen BankID themselves and other apps do is to add a configuration to use a test system. In your case you'd also need to use test-BankID's, the same you have fetched from demo.bankid.com yourselves for development.

So, when you submit your app to Apple, make sure to include a detailed instruction how to

- configure your app to use your test system,
- download the BankID app,
- configure the BankID app to use the "kundtest" configuration,
- download a BankID for test from demo.bankid.com.

Good luck!